# R: Dimension of reduced array

Tags: arrays, r, dimension

Let's say I have

```
x <- array(data=runif(a*b*c), dim=c(a,b,c))
f <- function(data)
{
   ...
   return(list(dim=dim(data))
}
```

How do I have to transform `data` inside of `f` in order to obtain

```
> f(data=x[,1,])
$dim
[1] a 1 c
```

instead of

```
> f(data=x[,1,])
$dim
[1] a c
```

?
Or is it impossible once `x[,1,]` has been inputted to `f`?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `drop=FALSE` to get the dimensions

```
 f <- function(data){
  return(list(dim=dim(data)))
 }

f(data=x[,1,, drop=FALSE])
#$dim
#[1] 3 1 3
```

#### data

```
 a <- 3
 b <- 2
 c <- 3
 x <- array(data=runif(a*b*c), dim=c(a,b,c))
```